# How is at called when a person can't feel the sense of recognition?

Tags: terms

I meet a person who doesn't feel a sense of recognition. When for example forgetting a name, and you give them a few choices, they can tell you whether one of the choices feels "right" through a corresponding bodily sensation.

How is it called when a person can't feel such a sense of recognition?

Comment: This question is at risk of being closed as [not framed in psychology or neuroscience](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2277/21). Try to include some background information (initial research) which makes you believe this 'thing' should be called anything in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There are several conditions associated with a disconnect between the feeling of recognizing something, the ability to name something, the ability to react to something appropriately, etc. called agnosias.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnosia

EDIT: See also "capgras delusion", which is possibly a more extreme version of what you're describing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capgras_delusion

Comment: As far as I understand the Wikipedia page it's about the inability to perceive something and categorize it but not about access to the corresponding feeling.
I don't find anything in the list on Wikipedia that's about feelings like that.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you're describing has been studied, but I edited my answer to include "Capgras Delusion", which seems like it might fit your description a bit better. Read the "causes" section, which says that the delusion might arise from the sufferer's inability to respond emotionally to people that they recognize.

Comment: Capgras delusion seems to be about beliefs and not about the inability to feel something.

Comment: Correct, but it is believe to be caused by an inability to feel the emotions associated with it. Per the article, "Ramachandran hypothesizes that the origin of Capgras syndrome is a disconnection between the temporal cortex, where faces are usually recognized (see temporal lobe), and the limbic system, involved in emotions. More specifically, he emphasizes the disconnection between the amygdala and the inferotemporal cortex."